# jQuery cookie value doesn't increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to display an alert when a visiter visits certain pages.

I tried this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var visited = 0;
if ($.cookie('visited')) {
visited = $.cookie('visited');
}
if (visited == 3) {
   alert('test');
} else {
    visited++;


    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 1000));
    $.cookie('visited', visited, {expires: 1});

    return false;
}
});
```

It works, but when I load my page 4 times, the value of `visited` stays at 3 and the alert function always display.

`visited` value does not increase and the cookie does not set a new value.

The other point is I want to set an additional parameter to my cookie: I want to display my alert function only in certain pages.

Comment: if visited is 3 under condition you have just alert u do not increment the count there should be an incremented counter after alert('test'); and also save it in cookie, else it will never increase from 3

Comment: Bear in mind that cookies get stored as strings and not as integers. So, something like `$.cookie('visited') + 1` would end up as `"31"` instead of `4`, if the value was stored as `"3"`. You can convert a string to an integer in JS with `parseFloat` or `parseInt` - for instance: `var num = '1'; var int = parseFloat(num);`

Comment: just remove the else and do all that stuff at the end (apart from the return false - not sure what that's for) rather than in the else

Comment: thanks, the else statement wan not necessary. The Fanyo SILIADIN and Pete's solution works.

rorymorris > thx i understand that, but i just remove the else statement and it did the trick

Vinod > Ok i see. if i do not parse the value, it will store it as a string. thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the else statement, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var visited = 0;
 if ($.cookie('visited')) {
  visited = $.cookie('visited');
 }
 if (visited == 3) {
   alert('test');
 }
 visited++;
 var date = new Date();
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (10 * 1000));
 $.cookie('visited', visited, {expires: 1});
 return false;

});
```

And think to indent your code

Comment: Thanks. As  rorymorris89, your solution works great !

And do you know where can i add a path parameter if i want to display my alert function only in certain pages ? 

Because this code works in each pages independently, it display the alert in each pages of the website, and i want it works globally in my website.

Thxx a lot

Answer (score 0):

here's how your code works.

```
When visited = 0; increment visited by 1;
when visited = 1; increment visited by 1;
when visited = 2; increment visited by 1;
when visited = 3; display alert.
```

now your visited is always 3. Therefore, the value doesn't change.

Comment: Thxx Ayush Bahuguna.